# drop down list selection based on 2 or more user input characters

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a drop down list in an ASP.net C# aspx page that contains several items:

- Avocado
- Eggplant
- Bananas
- Beets
- Broccoli
- Radishes

I want to enable near searching so a user can input:

- Ex1 - "Br" to get Broccoli instead of Radishes
- Ex2 - "Be" to get Beets instead of eggplant
- Ex3 - "Ba" to get Bananas instead of Avocado.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would implement this in pure JavaScript, if all the values are in a select list already.

Comment: I haven't tried anything to this point.  I just realized last night that the behavior is as described above (the list jumps to the first entry based on the letter pressed).  If you think javascript will work - please point me to an example. Thanks!

Comment: Yes - All values are passed to the control at page load.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you use the ASP.NET AJAX AutoComplete extender. It extends an ASP.NET TextBox control and then uses an AJAX call to get the autocomplete (i.e. suggestions), based on the input the user provided in the text box.

Read [Creating a Simple Auto-Complete TextBox](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_autocomplete_simple.ashx) for a tutorial-walkthrough of creating an autocomplete example.

Read [ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit documentation](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx) for a demo and description of the other ASP.NET AJAX extenders.

Comment: Karl - thanks for the links but I can see a problem that our client will point out immediately.  There still has to be a selection user action via mouse or arrow down.  What I'm looking for specifically is "Br" selects Broccoli (because that's the only string starting with those letters) and "Bri" set the selected index to -1 or no selection (Because that string doesn't exist in the list).  Do you know if this is possible with AJAX?